# Big O of this short code

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I would need to determin the Big O of this short code:

```
var iterations = 0;

function operation(num){
    iterations++;
    if (num == 0) return 1;
    return operation(Math.floor((num / 10) * 2));
}

var result = operation(1000);

alert('Result = ' + result + ', number of iterations = ' + iterations);
```

I came up with something around `O(log(logN))` but I'm not sure. Would you please help me a bit?

http://jsfiddle.net/qotbu5pq/2/

Comment: Please tell us how you got to `O(log(log(N)))` and we'll be able to tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: There is a great way to approximate it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: you are almost dividing operations by 5 until hit the zero result so should not it be `~log5(N)` iterations instead which means `O(log(N))` ...

Comment: @Spektre It is the needed answer, and should be set as such. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer from comment]

- you are almost dividing operations by 5 until hit the zero result
- so should not it be `~log5(N)` iterations instead which means `O(log(N))`
- sorry didn't want to add such trivial answer ...